# Como posso mudar o código que fiz para uma recursão

Tags: haskell

Este foi o código inicial que fiz:

```
count :: Char → String → Int
count x xs = length [x’ | x’← xs, x == x’]
```

Mudança para recursão:

```
count = length x' | x' <- xs
    | x == x'
```

O que estou a fazer mal? Ou é sequer possivel mudar para recursão o código inicial?

Answer (score 1):

Recursão, como já deve saber, é uma forma de definir funções, na qual a função é invocada dentro da sua própria definição. Este é um conceito muito usado, por exemplo, quando são apresentadas definições matemáticas.

Um dos exemplos mais comuns é a definição do conjunto dos números naturais N (neste caso consideremos que o 0 faz parte do conjunto):

```
1) 0  pertence a N
2) Se n pertence a N, então n+1 pertence também a N
```

A definição anterior, como a maioria das definições recursivas, está dividida em dois casos: o caso base (ou caso de paragem) e o passo recursivo, onde definimos regras para formular casos mais complexos em termos de casos mais simples.

Importante notar que, sem o caso(s) de paragem, a função normalmente entra num ciclo/laço infinito.

Aplicando a fórmula apresentada anteriormente ao seu problema, o número de ocorrências de um dado caractere (`c`) numa lista arbitrária (em que `x` representa a cabeça e `xs` a cauda) é:

```
1) 0 (zero) se a lista estiver vazia (caso base ou caso de paragem) 
2) Caso a lista não estiver vazia o resultado depende da comparação de `c` com o primeiro elemento da lista:
   - Se c é igual a x então o resultado é 1 + "número total de ocorrências de c na restante lista"
   - Se c é diferente de x, o resultado corresponde apenas ao "número total de ocorrências de c na restante lista".
```

Pode tentar agora, aplicar a fórmula anterior e tentar definir a sua função. Fica aqui também um exemplo, caso queira comparar a sua solução:

```
count :: Char -> String -> Int
count _ [] = 0   -- Caso de paragem/base
count c (x:xs) 
  | c == x    = 1 + count c xs
  | otherwise = count c xs
```